# How to read property values defined in a project from another project added as dependency?

Tags: spring-boot, dependencies, pom.xml, application.properties

i have 4 project
a-service
b-service
c-service
and the client-service.

This client-service is added as a dependency these three service. Client-service uses OAuth2RestTemplate and sets some credentials information. But in this structure; all the services uses same credentials. Now, i want to send service-specific property value from a, b and c services to client-service.

RestTemplateBuilder is a class from client-service.

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateBuilder {

    @Value("${client.prefix}")
    private String clientPrefix;
                  .
                  .
                  .
}
```

and i defined client.prefix in application.properties file in a-service.

```
client.prefix=aservice
```

but client-service can not read property value from application.properties in a-service. clientPrefix value is returning null.

i tried some solutions from stackoverflow but does not work for me. the solution i tried is like below;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoLG6.png)

so, how to read properties from dependency project classes in spring boot?